# I am unable to use id in codeigniter for jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a submit button in codeigniter which is as follow:

```
<?php
  form_open('admin/delete_article'),
  form_hidden('article_id', $article->id),
  form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'id'=>'btnDelete', 'value'=>'Delete', 'class'=>'btn btn-danger']),
  form_close();
  ?>
```

Actually this is a delete button and I want to add a fuctionality to confirm before delete, so I am using jquery by using `#btnDelete`, but that is not working. Source code is showing the input correctly, like:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger"  />
```

Jquery is loading correctly in the bottom of the page, but id and class of the input type is not working in jquery. My jquery code is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnDelete").click(function() {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure want to delete?", function(result) {
        alert("Confirm result: " + result);
        });
    });
 });
```

But id and class is not working even I am alerting something. Why is this so?

Update: This piece of code works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
      alert("Umar");
  });
});
```

I am unable to understand why any of the selectors of the input type is not working only, rest is working fine?

Comment: Is bootbox loaded?

Comment: No, even I am using alert, it is not working for id and class.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnDelete").click(function(){
        alert("Umar");
    });
}); //This is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnDelete', function() {
//code
});
```

Your code not working because it didn't load at the time, so can't catch the trigger.

Comment: What could be the possible reason for this? Basically there are two method to send data: GET & POST. GET was working, for example- <?= anchor("admin/edit_article/{$article->id}", 'Edit', ['class'=>'btn btn-warning']); ?>.....was fine. post that I used in the question was not working. Coding is all about your experience! Thanks for the support.